# How to generate a .js.map file against a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I modified a culture setting file from Kendo (kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.min.js) and was able to minify it. But I don't know how to go about creating a .map against it. My network log shows a 404 against that file. Is there a generator for map file? Here is the file:

```
!function (e) { "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["kendo.core.min"], e) : e() }(function () {
    !function (e, y) {
        kendo.cultures["en-US"] = {
            name: "en-US", numberFormat: {
                pattern: ["-n"],
                decimals: 2, 
                ",": ",", 
                ".": ".", 
                groupSize: [3], 
                percent: {
                    pattern: ["-n %", "n %"],
                    decimals: 2,
                    ",": ",",
                    ".": ".",
                    groupSize: [3],
                    symbol: "%"
                },
                currency: {
                    name: "UAE Dirham",
                    abbr: "AED",
                    pattern: ["-n $", "n $"],
                    decimals: 2,
                    ",": ",",
                    ".": ".",
                    groupSize: [3],
                    symbol: "د.إ."
                }
            },

            calendars: {
                standard: {
                    days: {
                        names: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
                        namesAbbr: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
                        namesShort: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"]
                    },
                    months: {
                        names: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                        namesAbbr: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
                    },
                    AM: ["AM", "am", "AM"],
                    PM: ["PM", "pm", "PM"],
                    patterns: {
                        d: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                        D: "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy",
                        F: "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                        g: "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm tt",
                        G: "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                        m: "MMMM d",
                        M: "MMMM d",
                        s: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",
                        t: "h:mm tt",
                        T: "h:mm:ss tt",
                        u: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
                        y: "MMMM, yyyy", Y: "MMMM, yyyy"
                    },
                    "/": "/",
                    ":": ":",
                    firstDay: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }(this)
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would guess it's the minifier's responsibility to generate a source map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For creating the minimized version of your javascript source code you can follow one of this options.

**Command line uglifi-js**:

For installing:

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

Running the command create the minimized file and the map:

```
uglifyjs  kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.js 
   --source-map kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.min.js.map 
   -o kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.min.js
```

Follow the instruction of this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js)

**Grunt Uglify:**

You can use Grunt.js uglify:

To install:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

The code in Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true   // this line is for create the map
      },
      files: {
        'kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.min.js': ['kendo.culture.en-US-Custom.js']
      }
    }
  }
});


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

Running the "uglify task" will create a minimized version of the file and the map.

Follow the instruction of this [link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify)

**Gulp Uglify:**

Alternatively you can do something similar with "Gulp Uglify".

Follow the instruction of this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifyjs)